# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView while trying to use ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying get the "Home" option to get back to the home screen which is the categories/options page. I'm using an ArrayList to populate the layout. The app was running fine until I added fragments. I added Fragments to Home and now every time I click on Home the app crashes and I get the above titled error.
Fairly new to android. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here are the code snippets: 
//ArrayList for the home screen

```
    final ArrayList<pojo> pojoArrayList = new ArrayList<pojo>();
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo("Hotels", R.drawable.hotel, R.drawable.gradient_splash));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo("Restaurants", R.drawable.restaurant, R.drawable.gradient_splash));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo("Places", R.drawable.places, R.drawable.gradient_splash));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo("Events", R.drawable.events, R.drawable.gradient_splash));
    pojoArrayList.add(new pojo("Information", R.drawable.info, R.drawable.gradient_splash));

    homeAdapter adapter = new homeAdapter(this, pojoArrayList);
    ListView listViewItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nav_list);
    listViewItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I thought that I made a mistake somewhere while calling so I tried it in different ways:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_hotel){
        fragment = new HotelFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_restaurants) {

    } 
    if(fragment!=null){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_list, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

These are the related XML layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".NavigationActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_navigation">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

2nd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/hotel_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/hotel" />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/grad"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_splash"
                android:alpha="0.4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:text="Hotels"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/textBlack"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

On running the app and clicking the Home option on the drawer i get the following error 
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView

Any help would be much appriciated.

Comment: The first argument in `fragmentTransaction.replace()` is the `ViewGroup` that the new `Fragment`'s `View` will be placed into. The `nav_list` ID is apparently a `ListView`, so that `FragmentTransaction` is trying to add the `Fragment` into that, but you cannot add `View`s to a `ListView` like that.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, do you  know of a work around to this?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure of exactly what you're trying to do, but if the first layout is the `Activity` layout, and you're trying to swap `Fragment`s in and out of that, then you should change the `<LinearLayout>` to a `<FrameLayout>`, add an `id` to it, and use that `R.id` in the `fragmentTransaction.replace()` call. However, a `FragmentTransaction` will not remove the `<ListView>` that's there, because it doesn't belong to a `Fragment`. That `<ListView>` should then have its own `Fragment` and layout, and you would use a `FragmentTransaction` to load that `ListView` `Fragment` at startup. Follow?

Comment: I tried using the <FrameLayout> id and its like as you said. the <ListView> is still there and the fragment just gets created on top of it. I dint actually follow the send part of your answer.

Comment: As mentioned, a `FragmentTransaction` will not remove that `<ListView>`, because it's not in a `Fragment`, so you want to put it in a `Fragment`. My suggestion is to move that `<ListView>` to a separate layout, create a `Fragment` class for it, and load that `Fragment` at startup; e.g., in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you so much for your answer. I did as you suggested and it did work.